# Flask: request, which returns information about previous request's status

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

In a `Flask` application, there is a route `/getFiles/`. When the route is called, downloading files is performed. The exact `localization` where the file would be downloaded is drawn just before the download starts. The question is: how to write a route `/checkGetFilesStatus/`, which returns status of the previous `/getFiles/` request (how many files have been downloaded so far)? The use of application would be as follows: user calls `/getFiles/` in a tab in his browser. Then, after some time, the user opens another tab in his browser and calls `/checkGetFilesStatus/`.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import urllib.request as req
import urllib.error
import uuid


file_list = ["https://test.com/file1.mp4", "https://test.com/file2.dll", "https://test.com/file3.avi"]
base_localization = "somewhere/"
@app.route('/getFiles/')
def get_files():
    for url in file_list:
        localization = base_localization + uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper() + url[url.rfind('.'):]
        try:
            req.urlretrieve(url, localization)
        except urllib.error.HTTPError:
            pass

@app.route('/checkGetFilesStatus/')
def check_get_files_status:
    # ...
    # ...
    # n = ...
    # ...
    return "Already downloaded " + str(n) + " from " + len(file_list) + " files."
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to implement your desired functionality.

One way that makes more sense, is to use a message queue like `Redis` or `RabbitMQ` and check status of `Acknowledged` or `Accepted` jobs in the queue.

The other way around this, is to create a global variable like `downloaded_files` and change that variable globally. This approach will only work for single workers and whenever you stop/start your script, It will get reset. (Because this way, you are keeping your message queue on `RAM`)